# How to store my key for encryption on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, cryptography

I am developing rest api system running on ec2 service.

My requirement is

1. encrypt/decrypt on plain text with AES256
2. generate key with pbkdf2
3. Store key on aws cloud system
4. Java

I tried to used KMS & Crypto sdk but it’s not working. (ex) result of encryption value is changed every time When I called method with same plaint text.

Do you have any ideas?

```
public String encrypt(String text) {
    String plaintext = text;
    try {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = getByteBuffer(plaintext);
        EncryptRequest encryptRequest = new EncryptRequest().withKeyId(key_arn).withPlaintext(byteBuffer);
        EncryptResult encryptResult = client.encrypt(encryptRequest);
        String ciphertext = getString(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptResult.getCiphertextBlob()));
        plaintext = ciphertext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return plaintext;
}

public String decrypt(String text) {
    String bb = null;
    try {
         byte[] ciphertextBytes = text.getBytes();

        DecryptRequest request = new DecryptRequest();
        request.setCiphertextBlob(ByteBuffer.wrap(ciphertextBytes));

        DecryptResult result = client.decrypt(request);

        // Convert to byte array
        byte[] plaintext = new byte[result.getPlaintext().remaining()];
        ByteBuffer a = result.getPlaintext().get(plaintext);
        bb = getString(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bb;
}
```

Comment: " but it’s not working" - can you provide an example of how do you use KMS so that it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin here my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer succinctly because there are a lot of details and background knowledge that go into crypto and using the AWS crypto capabilities correctly.

First to your specific question - different values from the same plaintext is ok and expected. `Encrypt` returns different values for the same plain text because it attaches additional data to the plain text, such as an `Initialization Vector (IV)`. This is a way to include non-deterministic data in the plain text precisely so that you **don't** end up with the exact same cipher text from the same plain text when using the same key.

More importantly, though, note that `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` are **not** general-purpose tools - they are designed to handle small payloads (< 8KB), specifically `Data Keys`. So where you go from here will depend on what kind of data you are encrypting. If you just need to decrypt a small value like a password, you can continue with `Encrypt/Decrypt`, and don't worry that two `Encrypt` operations produce different cipher texts. If you need to encrypt files or other arbitrary chunks of data, read on.

AWS promotes the idea of `Envelope Encryption`, which is the notion that the key used to actually en/decrypt is stored alongside data it protects, and is itself en/decrypted via a separate master key. In the AWS case, that's `Customer Master Key (CMK)`, which never leaves KMS.

So you can use `Encrypt` to encrypt an encryption key that you generate, or you could use the AWS method `GenerateDataKey` to 1) create a key and 2) encrypt it for you. That will return both a plaintext (base64) and cipher text version of the key. Use the plaintext in memory, store the cipher text to disk.

A more typical workflow would be something like:

- Call `GenerateDataKey` - you need to specify the `KeyId` and a `KeySpec` (`AES_128` or `AES_256`). There are also options to generate asymmetric keys.
- The result includes both a plain text and encrypted version of the generated key. Store the encrypted version.
- At some later time, call `Decrypt` when you need to use the key.
- Use the plaintext from that `Decrypt` method as the key in your local crypto code.

AWS actually provides a separate library to do all that for you - the AWS Encryption SDK, with support for a range of languages including Java. I've not used it extensively, but it provides the framework to do envelope encryption via best practices (which algorithms, master vs. data keys, etc). Take a look (link below).

Hope this helps; encryption is tough to get right.

For more info:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#enveloping
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector